# display format for results in console

Tags: c#

I am trying to display my results as follows:

```
-.-|-    [tab]  kt   
-.|--    [tab]  nm  
-.|-|-   [tab]  ntt
```

But this is my current output

```
-.-|-|  kt  
-.|--|  nm  
-.|-|-|  [tab]ntt
```

There is a `|` at the end of every Morse code which I would like to remove since it is at the end.

Also because the user can input Morse code with space between dots and dashes -  i noticed that it affects the alignment of the characters and not all of them get tabbed properly. The word tab isn't supposed to show i just wrote it in because I didn't know how to place a real tab.

```
private static readonly IDictionary<char, string> morseCode_alpha = new Dictionary<char, string>
{
    {'a', ".-"},{'b',"-..."}, {'c',"-.-."}, {'d',"-.."}, {'e',"."},
    {'f',"..-."}, {'g',"--."}, {'h',"...."},{'i',".."}, {'j',".---"}, 
    {'k',"-.-"}, {'l',".-.."}, {'m',"--"}, {'n',"-."}, {'o',"---"}, 
    {'p',".--."}, {'q',"--.-"}, {'r',".-."}, {'s',"..."}, {'t',"-"}, 
    {'u',"..-"}, {'v',"...-"}, {'w',".--"}, {'x',"-..-"}, {'y',"-.--"}, {'z',"--.."}
};

private static string ConvertMorseToText(string symbolCode)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder(4 * symbolCode.Length);

    foreach (char c in symbolCode)
        builder.Append(morseCode_alpha[c]);
    return builder.ToString();
}

private static string ConvertTextToMorse(char ch)
{
    if (morseCode_alpha.Keys.Contains(ch))
        return morseCode_alpha[ch];
    else
        return string.Empty;
}

private static string ConvertStringToMorse(string letters)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char ch in letters)
    {
        if (sb.Length != 0 && sb[sb.Length - 1] != ' ')
            sb.Append("|");
        sb.Append(ConvertTextToMorse(ch));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

private static IEnumerable<string> Permutations( string symbolCode)
{
    int n = symbolCode.Length;
    if (n == 0 || symbolCode.Length == 0)
        yield return " ";
    else
        foreach (var entry in morseCode_alpha)
            if (symbolCode.StartsWith(entry.Value))
                foreach (string next in Permutations(symbolCode.Substring(entry.Value.Length)))
                    yield return entry.Key + next;
}

private static void Write( string rest)
{
    string result = ConvertStringToMorse(rest);
    Console.Write(result+"\t");
    Console.WriteLine(rest);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string morseInput;
    string entered = "";
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Morse Code: \n");
        morseInput = Console.ReadLine().Replace(" ","");
        bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(morseInput, @"^[-.]+$");
        if (isValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nAll permutations:\n");
            string morse = ConvertMorseToText(entered);
            string permutations = morseInput.Substring(morse.Length);
            Write(permutations);
            var nexts = new List<string>(Permutations(permutations));
            foreach (string next in nexts)
                Write(next);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nFormat of morse must be only dots and dashes.");
            Console.WriteLine("Parameter name: "+morseInput+"\n");
        }
    }
    while (morseInput.Length != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draft version of the method:

```
private static string ConvertStringToMorse(string letters)
{
    var result = string.Join("|",
        letters
            .Select(ConvertTextToMorse)
            .Where(morse => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(morse)));
    return result;
}
```

Update:

Please note that the `entered` variable is used **only once**: when defined - **empty string is assigned**. Then the `ConvertMorseToText(entered)` method is called: **it always returns empty string for the empty string argument**. After this assignment `string permutations = morseInput.Substring(morse.Length);` the `permutations` variable will store exactly the same value as `morse` variable (because `morse.Length` is always 0).

So, it seems that the `entered` variable and the `ConvertMorseToText()` method are useless (**both can be safely removed**):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Morse Code: ");

        string morseInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(morseInput))
        {
            // Empty or consists only of white-space characters
            break;
        }

        morseInput = morseInput.Replace(" ", "");

        bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(morseInput, @"^[-.]+$");
        if (isValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("All permutations:");
            Console.WriteLine();
            var nexts = Permutations(morseInput).ToList();
            foreach (string next in nexts)
                Write(next);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Format of morse must be only dots and dashes.");
            Console.WriteLine("Parameter name: {0}", morseInput);
        }
    }
    while (true);
}
```

Update 2:
Consider using `TryGetValue()` method of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead of `Keys.Contains` and `[]` (indexer) i.e. do not perform look-up twice:

```
private static string ConvertTextToMorse(char ch)
{
    string result;
    return morseCode_alpha.TryGetValue(ch, out result) ? result : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Works well Thanks!! Also w0lf's answer is right as well and works well: `var chars = letters.Select(ConvertTextToMorse).Except(new[] { "" });`

Comment: I also noticed when i am printing my results that the first line of results is the same thing that i have entered for input. How can i remove showing my input in the results again?

Comment: @Amina, try to remove this line `Write(permutations);` of the `Main()` method.

Comment: one more questions - do you think any of the three methods of string - text - morse code converting can be combined or is the way that i have it is proper?

Comment: amazingly helpful.. may i be greedy and ask for one more suggestion? With my current `do while` loop how can i have the program exit with the user presses `enter` for input? because currently when i press enter it gives me my error message and then says `press any key to continue...` i press then i exit.

Comment: @Amina, `Press any key to continue...` message is by design if you're running the application using Ctrl+F5 hot-key from Visual Studio. Proof: try to run compiled exe-file manually from Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

And, to answer the other part of the question...

Tabstops are fixed for console writing, so it would be better to use something like String.PadRight

so, your code could be:

```
private static void Write(string rest)
{
    string result = ConvertStringToMorse(rest);
    Console.Write(result.PadRight(20));
    Console.WriteLine(rest);
}
```

Comment: PadRight Worked Great! Lifesaver - this should be a post on its own - i got two answers for two different things. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead this code:

```
Console.Write(result+"\t");
Console.WriteLine(rest);
```

Use

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,-10}{1,-10}", result, rest);
```

Then you will see two columns (each max 10 charachters) with left alignment. Or remove "-" sign if you want right alignment.

Comment: sometimes `result` can exceed 10 chars. The correct way to do this is to compute in advance what should be the max supported length for the input and use `PadRight` like David Hope suggested in his answer.